# What storage format does the SunOne mail server use?

Tags: email-server, sun-one

I'm looking for documentation on the storage format the SunOne email server is using. The possible candidates are [maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) and [mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox). I seem not to be able to find comprehensive documentation.

Comment: Just open some of the files. Maildir uses one email per file, and mbox concatenates every email in the folder into one big fat file. It should be obvious if it's one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's your basic mbox, according to [the old Sun administration docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19563-01/819-4428/bgaxt/index.html).

Comment: great, thx a lot for the link. Was hunting for that